# two questions about amsart

Tags: amsart

If I'm writting a mathematical paper and I'm using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{amsart}
```

on the first page there's the titel at the very top of the page. On the second page there's the authors name. How could I fix it, such that on every page there's the title at the very top of the page.

second question is about the title. Is it possible to construct a subtitle which will not appear at the top on every page (see question 1). For completeness here's the template I used:

```
    \documentclass{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\title{}

%    Remove any unused author tags.

%    author one information
\author{}
\address{}
\curraddr{}
\email{}
\thanks{}

%    author two information
\author{}
\address{}
\curraddr{}
\email{}
\thanks{}

\subjclass[2000]{Primary }
%    For articles to be published after 1 January 2010, you may use
%    the following version:
%\subjclass[2010]{Primary }

\keywords{}

\date{}

\dedicatory{}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The reason for question 2 is the following: I want a subtitle like: Thesis of {\author}. Is there a better template than this for this purpose? I'm very thankful for your help.

cheers

math

Edit: As mbrok suggested, here's my code:

```
    documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{amsart}

    % \documentclass{amsart} says to use the AMS article document class.
    % [12pt,oneside] says to use the 12pt and oneside options.
    % If you don't want these options, just say \documentstyle{amsart}.

    % After the document class declaration comes the preamble.
    % The preamble begins here.



          \usepackage{amssymb}
          \usepackage{amsmath}
          \usepackage{amsthm}
          \usepackage{amsfonts}
          \usepackage[english]{babel}
          \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
          \usepackage{enumerate}
          \usepackage{graphicx}

       % Next we use \newtheorem to specify our theorem-like environments
       % (theorem, definition, etc.) and how to display and number them.
       %
       % Note: The \theoremstyle declarations affect the appearance of the
       % Theorems, Definitions, etc.

          \theoremstyle{plain}
          \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
          \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
          \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
          \newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}
          \theoremstyle{definition}
          \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

          \theoremstyle{remark}
          \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

       % The preamble is also a good place to define new commands and macros.
       % This part of the preamble is strictly optional according to your taste.

          \newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
          \newcommand{\nil}{\varnothing}
          \newcommand{\N}{{\mathbb N}}
          \newcommand{\A}{{\marhcal A}}

       % The following mysterious maneuver gets rid of AMS junk at the top
       % and bottom of the first page.

          \makeatletter
          \def\@setcopyright{}
          \def\serieslogo@{}
          \makeatother


    % This ends the preamble.  We now proceed to the document itself.

          \begin{document}


    % First we specify the top matter (author, title, etc).
    %
    % Note: All of the top matter items are optional and can be omitted.
    % But you will probably want to specify at least the author and title
    % and perhaps an abstract.

       % author information

       % first author 

       \author{}      % 
\address{}
       \email{}

       % second author

       %\author{}

       % the address where the research was carried out
       % \address{}

       % current address, usually not needed because it is the same as the
       % regular address

       % \email{}

       % title





       \title{}
       \xdef\shorttitle{\shorttitle{}}


       % Note that the short title for running heads goes in square
       % brackets.  This is optional.  The long title goes in curly
       % braces.  In the long title, line breaks are indicated by \\.

       % abstract (optional)
       \begin{abstract}

       \end{abstract}

       % AMS subject classifications (used in AMS journals)
       \subjclass[2010]{Primary 46N30; Secondary 46E30,54D30}

       % AMS keywords (used in AMS journals)
       \keywords{}

       % acknowledge support, etc
       % \thanks{This research was partially supported by NSF grant
       %  DOA-123456789.}
       % \thanks{We would like to thank our colleagues for their helpful
       %  criticism.}

       % dedication
       \dedicatory{}

       % today's date, or fill in whatever date you prefer
       \date{\today}

    % This ends the top matter information.
    % We can now tell LaTeX to display the top matter.

       \maketitle

    % Having displayed the top matter, we now proceed to the body of the
    % article.

    % The body of the article is divided into sections.
    % Each section begins with a \section command.

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
       \section{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Try the `oneside` option:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{amsart}
   ```
2. Try

   ```
   \title[Title for running head]{Title for the first page}
   ```

And you'd better not use `\author` in the way you mentioned in your post; this is only a macro setting the actual title.  If you do not want to repeat the title, you may use e.g. this (a bit dirty) hack:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,oneside]{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\author[A.\,U. Thor]{Andrew U. Thor}
\title[Short title]{A longish, baroque-style title}
\xdef\shorttitle{\shorttitle{} -- Thesis of \noexpand\MakeUppercase{\shortauthors}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

(As usual, you may omit the `[...]` parameters for "short versions" of author name and title.)

Comment: @ mbrok: Thank you for your answer! I guess my question was not that clear. My problem in 1) is: After the title page there's the content and then the actual paper starts. From this page on there's at the very top of the page the title. On the next page there's the author's name at the very top of the page...and so on. Now what I want is: On every page the title or (if not possible) nothing. But I do not want that the author's name and the title is changing form page to page. Hopefully you understand what I want :).

Comment: If I use your \xdef then the author's name and \shorttiel - Thesis of.. is also changing from page to page.

Comment: @math: what do you mean?  Nothing is changing for me.  I'll include a full MWE for my solution in a moment.

Comment: @ mbork: Strange, I replaced your code with mine and everything went fine. But using my code it is changing from page to page. However I'm very thankful for your help and I'm very happy to get a satisfactory reply :)

Comment: @math: if you want, you can (1) put your (non-working) code here so that someone (possibly me) could help you or (2) look at my profile, find my email there and send me an email with your document.  But (1) is a preferred way;).

Comment: @ mbork: I added my code in my question. Thank you a lot for your help. However please feel free to not correct my code. Since it works now with your code. I don't want to waste your time :) As mentioned the code was a template from the web. Thanks again!

Comment: @math: something is wrong with your code, it is incomplete!

Comment: what do you mean with incomplete? What's missing is the the text itself and \end{document} but this doesn't matter, right?

Comment: @math: right, but without that I can't reproduce the problem you wrote about (changing running head).